# making first letter of input uppercase with split in python

Tags: python, for-loop, input, split, uppercase

I got most of the code down but I am having issues getting the string to space back out after making the first letter of each word uppercase

here's what I have so far:

message = input('Write a short message.')

new_message = message.split()

glue = ""

for item in new_message:

glue += item[0].upper() + item[1:]

print(glue)

Comment: What about just: `message.capitalize()`?

Comment: You might find [this documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#string-methods) useful; regarding built-in string methods.

Answer (score 2):

try with:

```
message.capitalize()
```

Comment: thank you but I am trying to capitalize each word within the string separately

Answer (score 0):

If you want to capitalize each word you can try capitalize() and the code will look like this:

```
  message = input('Write a short message.')
    
  new_message = message.split()
  cap_message = [x.capitalize() for x in new_message]
  print(cap_message)
```

- message.split() - split the string into a list using default separator which is any whitespace. The result is a list of words.
- capitalize each word in the list using [List Comprehention](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions). The list of capitalized words is saved in cap_message variable for code clarity.
- print the list of capitalized words

Comment: Ohhh ok that was simple

Comment: Perhaps add some explanation as to *what* this is doing and *why*, for the educational benefit of the OP, as list comp isn’t obvious to a beginner.  And *why* the `split` method splits on whitespace without being told to is also not obvious.